# Limited dissolve many faces

Tags: mesh, faces

I have mesh 700k faces and limited dissolve work bad. File is big, 250 mb. Is some practic to decrease number of faces and not loose geometry?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the *Decimate Modifier*?

Comment: No, i dont know this modifier, but work. Very thanks.

Comment: Is this a quads based mesh? If so the *Decimate* modifier set to *Unsubdivide* may work well here without ruining the topology too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to loose a geometry and overall shape of the mesh you may use a ***Decimate Modifier*** to do it. As you can see after setting it up (reducing the *Collapse's Ratio* factor to 0.15) I reduced the *verts count* from over 2.000.000 to over 300.000.
[image]