# How to simplify CAD models?

Tags: animation, mesh, blend4web

I am trying to make an interactive website (like www.3dtuning.com) using CAD models from the engineering team (.stl ) with Blend4web PLugin. But the output file size (html) was too big  (1.2GB!) so that the browser didn't display it. Then I reduced the size to 500 MB using *Meshlab*. The output now opens in a browser but small parts of the models are missing and 500 MB is still too big for a webpage.

Some people I spoke to say that I should model in Blender on top of the CAD models, use the Blender Models and discard the original CAD Models. This seems redundant because I am remodeling after the engineering team has already modeled it once.

Is this a normal procedure for making such websites?

I have already read other similar questions on the site, but they don't seem to have the answer.

Comment: You may want to try using Blender's limited dissolve feature OR [decimate tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77297/limited-dissolve-many-faces), it will usually clean up the faces pretty good, but it usually depends on the geometry. Because CAD models are usually more boxy than organic models, this should help a LOT.

Comment: From my own experience - make new models. This procedure is called retopology. Sometimes with simple models you can go with cleaning up mesh from CAD, but most of the time it's quicker to make new one.

Comment: You can't use the CAD models in realtime graphics they look horrible (made by engineers, not artists) and they have their faces in all the wrong places. If you want to make a good impression you need a layer that replaces CAD models with properly made realtime graphics models.